# scala - casting Any to accomodate String and Double

Tags: scala, collections

I want to convert a Map[String,Any] to Map[String,String]
but running into exceptions for some cases.

```
scala> val m2 = m1.map( x => (x._1,x._2.asInstanceOf[String]))  // String fails
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

scala> val m2 = m1.map( x => (x._1,x._2.asInstanceOf[Double]))  // Double also fails
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

scala> val m2 = m1.take(2).map( x => (x._1,x._2.asInstanceOf[Double])) //Passed for 2 elements
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(data_diff -> 0.0, pos_diff -> 0.0)

scala> val m2 = m1.take(4).map( x => (x._1,x._2.asInstanceOf[Double])) // Fails for more elements
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

A direct toString also gives NullPointerException

```
scala> val m2 = m1.map( x => (x._1,x._2.toString))
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe all you want to do is just call `toString` rather than casting.

Comment: `map` with `toString` to forcibly convert to `String` whether it makes sense or not, OR `collect { case (k, v: String) => k -> v }` to just pick these pairs which has actual `String` as the second element.

Comment: I need all the elements from the map value converted to String

Comment: Where does the input map comes from? Do you know for sure the possible types of the values? What kind of converted string do you expect if a value of the map is itself a map?

Comment: it is actually coming from a table output.. with one row, column name as map keys and column values as "Any".. the value of the map will be plain data type only

Answer (score 2):

I think your second attempt, a direct call toString is the way to go. Could it be that your Map contains null values? You should filter them first.

`val m2 = m1.filterNot(_._2 == null).map( x => (x._1,x._2.toString))`

A `filter` and `map` can be written more concise with `collect`:

`val m2 = m1.collect { case (key, value) if value != null => key -> value.toString }`

Comment: yes.. it helps.. Any idea if I could convert null to string value of "null"

Comment: `map { case (k, v) => (k, if (v == null) "null") else v.toString) }`

Comment: `Option(v).map(_.toString).getOrElse("null")`